# How to get the URL of a redirect with Python

Tags: python, redirect, urllib2

In Python, I'm using urllib2 to open a url. This url redirects to another url, which redirects to yet another url.

I wish to print out the url after each redirect.

For example

-> = redirects to

A -> B -> C -> D

I want to print the URL of B, C and D (A is already known because it's the start URL).

Comment: why not use the requests module, `actualURL = requests.head(passedurl,  timeout=100.0 , headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}).headers.get('location', passedurl)` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably the best way is to subclass `urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler`. Dive Into Python's [chapter on redirects](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html) may be helpful.

Answer (score 48):

You can easily get D by just asking for the current URL.

```
req = urllib2.Request(starturl, datagen, headers)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
finalurl = res.geturl()
```

To deal with the intermediate redirects you'll probably need to [build your own opener](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.build_opener), using [HTTPRedirectHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#httpredirecthandler-objects) that records the redirects.

Comment: It solves the more common question of "what is the url I arrived to"?

Comment: here is a similar answer using `requests`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20475712/309483

Answer (score 4):

For Python 3, the solution with [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) is much simpler:

```py
import urllib


def resolve(url):
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url).geturl()
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! However, is this really a full solution? The OP was looking for intermediate redirect URLs `B` and `C` as well, not just the final destination `D`.