# How to get current url of a parsed HTML page in Python with lxml?

Tags: python, parsing, url, lxml

In Python I'm parsing various URLs to find some elements in the body of the returned document. I'm using lxml for this, like so:

```
import lxml.html as html

url = 'http://www.linktowebsite.com'
data = html.parse(url)

for d in data.xpath('body'):
    code code code
```

Some urls however redirect to a different page and I want to know the current URL after the redirect. I haven't found anything in the documentation of lxml about this.

How can I find the current URL of the parsed/redirected page?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/4902523/776084

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `data.docinfo.URL` [documentation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.DocInfo-class.html)

Example:

```
In [22]: data = html.parse('http://httpbin.org/redirect/2')

In [23]: data.docinfo.URL
Out[23]: u'http://httpbin.org/get'
```