# How do I modify my "download" function to work with 301/302 redirects?

Tags: python, http, url

```
def download(source_url):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(20)
        agents = ['Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1041.0 Safari/535.21','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20120403211507 Firefox/12.0']
        ree = urllib2.Request(source_url)
        ree.add_header('User-Agent',random.choice(agents))
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(ree)
        htmlSource = resp.read()
        return htmlSource
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        return ""
```

I wrote this download function. How do I make it work with 301/302?

Ex: http://tumblr.com/tagged/long-reads my function doesn't work with this url.

Comment: I can `urlopen` that URL just fine...

Comment: @larsmans did you try my function with it?

Comment: Yes. Works just fine (Python 2.6 on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to get the HTTP response code, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140661/python-get-http-response-code-from-a-url).

If code is 30x, you have to get new url, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902523/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-redirect-with-python).

Then you can recursively call your function download() with new URL.

You should also add one parametr as redirection counter to avoid infinite looping.

Answer (score 0):

If a redirect (301/2) code is returned, urllib2 *should* follow that redirect automatically.

Look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554446/how-do-i-prevent-pythons-urllib2-from-following-a-redirect). If it does not follow the redirect in your case this article examines in detail [redirects handling](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html).