# Get url of a page after redirecting in Python

Tags: python, url

I have a url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=559149457475028&redirect_uri=https://calm-refuge-2106.herokuapp.com/&scope=publish_stream
```

It redirects to another page with url:

```
https://calm-refuge-2106.herokuapp.com/?code=AQAoBPyS4lKynHM4lylFHChFyO775T-49A1j8DbTGO9iiyoKnkDv0naSWMSvJ26ISt50fTUGcYH8QfUdLwt4sLBQ9noNmBCuUsze4rVSjxCcJ1pbfcLpfy2OyLB5DMg7sOWr_q5dEHNEd9eXoeRepmjFDU7GyEUx6WrjDtIOcusH4prnPGhQ2gHopJC54AeflMC9bh6fP2R6OhAJhVCVMHNvIT2wwTB8DG46yoRP1GAqN-d2vm8RwOC93vY-Xv_HvGQKwhRxbpVlk2vWTMQ40F1rbaw_zJNz7oBtz7qDUQkxI3RcE6dWw5GEzPcFMFuD1jw#_=_
```

where I need to take only *code* query.

When I use *urllib.urlopen* to open the url and then *geturl* method to returned file-like object it returns something like this: `https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=559149457475028&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fcalm-refuge-2106.herokuapp.com%252F%26scope%3Dpublish_stream%26client_id%3D559149457475028%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcalm-refuge-2106.herokuapp.com%2F%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=page`

It's clearly not what i was looking for.

How can I get a url after redirecting in Python?

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/login.php` I'd say it's the url of Facebook login page. Your `GET` request is not authentified.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm logged in on Facebook.

Comment: Yes, you are logged in Facebook in your browser, but your python application does not use the authentication information stored in your browser. You need to login to Facebook in your python application, save the cookie information about the login and use this to access the webpage afterwards.

Comment: I tried to use pyfb library which makes this work under the hood. But the problem that I need to pass access token manually. How can I authenticate python in this app concretely?

Answer (score 1):

try `urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler`

Comment: This post also refers to HTTPRedirectHandler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902523/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-redirect-with-python

Comment: urllib2 didn't help. Every time it gives the same url. I don't understand how to use HTTPRedirectHandler in this case.