# Python Requests library redirect new url

Tags: python, http, redirect, python-requests

I've been looking through the Python Requests documentation but I cannot see any functionality for what I am trying to achieve.

In my script I am setting `allow_redirects=True`.

I would like to know if the page has been redirected to something else, what is the new URL.

For example, if the start URL was: `www.google.com/redirect`

And the final URL is `www.google.co.uk/redirected`

How do I get that URL?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902578/4607733) for dealing with  `urllib2 `

Comment: check my solution using webbrowser here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503861/to-get-redirected-url-with-requests/70869177#70869177)

Answer (score 216):

You are looking for the [request history](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history).

The `response.history` attribute is a list of responses that led to the final URL, which can be found in `response.url`.

```
response = requests.get(someurl)
if response.history:
    print("Request was redirected")
    for resp in response.history:
        print(resp.status_code, resp.url)
    print("Final destination:")
    print(response.status_code, response.url)
else:
    print("Request was not redirected")
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/redirect/3')
>>> response.history
(<Response [302]>, <Response [302]>, <Response [302]>)
>>> for resp in response.history:
...     print(resp.status_code, resp.url)
... 
302 http://httpbin.org/redirect/3
302 http://httpbin.org/redirect/2
302 http://httpbin.org/redirect/1
>>> print(response.status_code, response.url)
200 http://httpbin.org/get
```

Comment: httpbin.org is giving 404s for some reason, but httpbingo.org (same URL scheme) worked just fine for me.

Comment: @PrestonBadeer:  This is a known issue: https://github.com/postmanlabs/httpbin/issues/617. It's not crucial that the demo works for the answer, luckily.

Answer (score 99):

This is answering a slightly different question, but since I got stuck on this myself, I hope it might be useful for someone else.

If you want to use `allow_redirects=False` and get directly to the first redirect object, rather than following a chain of them, and you just want to get the redirect location directly out of the 302 response object, then `r.url` won't work.  Instead, it's the "Location" header:

```
r = requests.get('http://github.com/', allow_redirects=False)
r.status_code  # 302
r.url  # http://github.com, not https.
r.headers['Location']  # https://github.com/ -- the redirect destination
```

Comment: Thank you - this boosted my URL referral script (which had thousands of urls) by several seconds.

Comment: Do you know what is up with `r.next`? I thought that would contain a `PreparedRequest` pointing to the redirect URL, but that does not seem to be the case...

Comment: Worth adding that this answer will only give you the first redirect URL.
if this url, when visited, would have normally redirect again to a new url, you will miss it.

Answer (score 54):

I think **`requests.head`** instead of **`requests.get`** will be more safe to call when handling url redirect. Check a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2618):

```
r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
print(r.url)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Short and sweet.

Comment: @Volatil3: Not all servers respond to a HEAD request the same way the would with a GET.

Comment: For me this method worked in extracting the final redirect URL, saved considerable amount of manual effort for 30K URL

Answer (score 48):

the documentation has this blurb https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.github.com')
r.url
#returns https://www.github.com instead of the http page you asked for
```

Comment: This is awesome. For whatever reason, my `response.history` was empty when getting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random even though there's an obvious 302. Luckily I only wanted the last one, so this did that trick. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

For python3.5, you can use the following code:

```
import urllib.request
res = urllib.request.urlopen(starturl)
finalurl = res.geturl()
print(finalurl)
```

Comment: this is the correct answer for Python 3.5, it took me a while to find, thanks

Comment: Can you finish your answer please, If you found out how to do redirect with python3? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the following function to get the full URL from a short URL (bit.ly, t.co, ...)

```py
import requests

def expand_short_url(url):
    r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=False)
    r.raise_for_status()
    if 300 < r.status_code < 400:
        url = r.headers.get('Location', url)

    return url
```

Usage (short URL is this question's url):

```py
short_url = 'https://tinyurl.com/' + '4d4ytpbx'
full_url = expand_short_url(short_url)
print(full_url)
```

Output:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are applicable where the final url exists/working fine.
In case, final URL doesn't seems to work then below is way to capture all redirects.
There was scenario where final URL isn't working anymore and other ways like url history give error. 
**Code Snippet**

```
long_url = ''
url = 'http://example.com/bla-bla'
try:
    while True:
        long_url = requests.head(url).headers['location']
        print(long_url)
        url = long_url
except:
    print(long_url)
```

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't able to use requests library and had to go different way. Here is the code that I post as solution to this post. ([To get redirected URL with requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503861/to-get-redirected-url-with-requests/70869177#70869177))

This way you actually open the browser, wait for your browser to log the url in the history log and then read last url in your history. I wrote this code for google chrom, but you should be able to follow along if you are using different browser.

```
import webbrowser
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import shutil

webbrowser.open("https://twitter.com/i/user/2274951674")
#source file is where the history of your webbroser is saved, I was using chrome, but it should be the same process if you are using different browser
source_file = 'C:\\Users\\{your_user_id}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History'
# could not directly connect to history file as it was locked and had to make a copy of it in different location
destination_file = 'C:\\Users\\{user}\\Downloads\\History'
time.sleep(30) # there is some delay to update the history file, so 30 sec wait give it enough time to make sure your last url get logged
shutil.copy(source_file,destination_file) # copying the file.
con = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\{user}\\Downloads\\History')#connecting to browser history
cursor = con.execute("SELECT * FROM urls")
names = [description[0] for description in cursor.description]
urls = cursor.fetchall()
con.close()
df_history = pd.DataFrame(urls,columns=names)
last_url = df_history.loc[len(df_history)-1,'url']
print(last_url)

>>https://twitter.com/ozanbayram01
```