# Find the redirected URL with Python requests library or otherwise

Tags: python, python-requests

This URL:

http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/newiyp/UrlRedirect?applicationInd=yp&searchType=68&searchCriteria=multiple+choices&accessType=8&advertiserName=Multiple+Choices&url=62CE8F02A1BE04A51C81F85D1CE8B54DFC608A9CDA925C15EED5DA6DD90E3F7DC99CFF77216D1D1083877BA841EB97C3

Redirects to:

http://www.callmyname.sg/view/Multiple+Choices/Uk9JRC9TRzA0SkstQkJDNkRFNTEuMTNCNS9FRDY5LUE4NzgtRUY=

When using `requests`, I get:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/newiyp/UrlRedirect?applicationInd=yp&searchType=68&searchCriteria=multiple+choices&accessType=8&advertiserName=Multiple+Choices&url=62CE8F02A1BE04A51C81F85D1CE8B54DFC608A9CDA925C15EED5DA6DD90E3F7DC99CFF77216D1D1083877BA841EB97C3"
response = requests.get(url)
response.url
```

It returns the same first URL, not the redirected URL.

Comment: Duplicate of [Python Requests library redirect new url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a sample. I used "bit.ly", because I got *403* using your URL.

```
>>> url = "http://bit.ly/18SuUzJ"
>>> r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
>>> r.status_code
    301
>>> r.headers['Location']
    'http://stackoverflow.com/'
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Requests doc, `r.history` is what you need.

Comment: r.history returns empty list

Comment: @muffinz When I try it myself I got 403 forbidden. Perhaps it's not allowed for visiting? Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A `HEAD` request could be faster than a `GET` request. That's even if the `GET` redirects are not followed. This is because `HEAD` returns the headers only, not the content, whereas `GET` returns both.

```py
import requests

>>> response = requests.head('https://bit' + '.ly/pyre', allow_redirects=False)

>>> response.is_redirect
True

>>> response.headers['Location']
'http://www.python.org/doc/current/library/re.html'
```

The above approach should identify exactly one level of redirect. Also to keep it simple, I use `requests.head` instead of `requests.Session().head`.

Answer (score 0):

This site seems to require a session cookie in order for the redirect to work.

`r.url` does in fact show the URL after the redirect ([unless you have changed the configuration](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)).

The problem with your redirect is that it never happens if the cookie isn't already there. You can test that by visiting the URL with a browser in incognito/private mode. You will see an error message from http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/ with a status code 200. On a reload you will then be redirected.

Strangely, I cannot get a redirect even with a `requests` session. Using a real browser's user agent string doesn't seem to help, either. You might have to compare the two requests in detail to find what the crucial difference is.

The code I tried looks like this:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'user_agent',}
s = requests.Session()
url = "http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/"
r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
url = "http://www.yellowpages.com.sg/newiyp/UrlRedirect?applicationInd=yp&searchType=68&searchCriteria=multiple+choices&accessType=8&advertiserName=Multiple+Choices&url=62CE8F02A1BE04A51C81F85D1CE8B54DFC608A9CDA925C15EED5DA6DD90E3F7DC99CFF77216D1D1083877BA841EB97C3"
r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
r.url
```