# Python Requests unable to get redirected URL

Tags: python, python-requests

I have defined the following function to get the redirected URLs using Requests library. However i get the error `KeyError: 'location'`

```
def get_redirected_url(r_url):
    r = requests.get(r_url, allow_redirects=False)
    url = r.headers['Location']
    return url
```

Calling the function

```
get_redirected_url('http://omgili.com/ri/.wHSUbtEfZQujfav8g98PjRMi_ogV.5EwBTfg476RyS2Gqya3tDAwNIv8Yi8wQ9AK4.U2mxeyq2_xbUjqsOx8NYY8r0qgxD.4Bm2SrouZKnrg1jqRxEfVmGbtTaKTaaDJtOjtS46fYr6A5UJoh9BYxVtDGJIsbSfgshRXR3FVr4-')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in get_redirected_url
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'location'
```

Is it failing because the redirection waits for 5 seconds? If so, how do we incorporate that as well?

I have tried the other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110498/is-there-an-easy-way-to-request-a-url-in-python-and-not-follow-redirects) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135837/how-do-i-find-out-the-redirected-url-with-python-requests-library-or-otherwise). But unable to crack it.

Comment: Is the url you are passing is correct because your code is working fine  and doing redirection.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple: r.headers doesn't have 'Location' key. You may have use the wrong key.

Edit: the site you want to browse with requests is protected.