# Python - Requests module, getting the domain name?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to build a web crawler using the `requests` module,
and basically what I want it to do is go to a webpage, get all the `href`'s and then write them to a text file.

So far my code looks like this:

```
def getLinks(url):
response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll("a"):
    print("Link:"+str(link.get("href")))
```

which work on some sites
but the one that I'm trying to use it on the `href`'s isn't full domain names like "www.google.com" instead they're like...paths to a directory that redirects to the link?

looks like this:

```
href="/out/101"
```

and if i try to write that in to a file it looks like this

```
 1. /out/101
 2. /out/102
 3. /out/103
 4. /out/104
```

which isn't really what I wanted.

soo how do I go about getting the domain names from these links?

Answer (score 4):

This means that the URLs are *relative* to the current. To get the full URLs, use [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

```
from urlparse import urljoin

for link in soup.findAll("a"): 
    full_url = urljoin(url, link.get("href"))
    print("Link:" + full_url)
```

Comment: ah right, but that only gives the the full url of the page that redirects to the actual site, but how do i get the url of the site that i get redirected to? :P

Comment: @stav make a request to it and get the `response.url`. If you would need to record the redirect chain, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. It will give you all the links from a website. If you know the `base url` of the website, then you can extract all the other urls from it. Whole web scraping code is here [WebScrape](https://github.com/rakeshsukla53/enigma.io/blob/master/Part%202%20-%20Web%20Scrape/solution.py)

```
import requests
import lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extractLinks(url, base):
        '''
        Return links from the website
        :param url: Pass the url
        :param base: this is the base links
        :return: list of links
        '''
        links = [] #it will contain all the links from the website
        try:
            r = requests.get(url)
        except:
            return []
        obj = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
        potential_links = obj.xpath("//a/@href")
        links.append(r.url)
        #print potential_links
        for link in potential_links:
            if base in link:
                links.append(link)
            else:
                if link.startswith("http"):
                    links.append(link)

                elif base.endswith("/"):
                    if link.startswith("/"):
                        link = link.lstrip("/")
                        link = base + link
                    else:
                        link = base + link
                    links.append(link)

        return links

extractLinks('http://data-interview.enigmalabs.org/companies/',
    'http://data-interview.enigmalabs.org/')
```