# Get the URLs of all redirects

Tags: php, python, redirect, request

I want to get the URLs of all redirects.

Example:

> `a.com` redirects to `b.com` and `b.com` redirects to `c.com`.

I know how to get `a.com` and `c.com`.

How can I get `b.com`?

Comment: I think it's a duplicate for this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url

Comment: Thanks. What a shame I seen response.history before and ignored it.