# Selenium with PhantomJS does not get redirected

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, redirect

For a concrete example of the problem, when I go to the following address in a regular browser:

`http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS16/paper/viewFile/13951/13240`

I get re-directed to `https`:

`https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS16/paper/viewFile/13951/13240`

I tried the following in the Python interactive shell:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> driver.get("http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS16/paper/viewFile/13951/13240")
>>> driver.current_url
u'http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS16/paper/viewFile/13951/13240'
```

As is seen from the output, the re-direction did not happen. I waited a bit and issued `driver.current_url` once again, but the same output came out. How do I cause Selenium to get re-directed the way it happens in a regular browser?

**EDIT:** I tried to send Selenium directly to the `https` address and it would not go! Could it be because that url is a file? If this is a normal behavior, then how can I find out the file's url when I only have the `http` link?

Comment: Try giving it some time to redirect. Use a `sleep`. Or you could also try to run it from a file

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 It does not make a difference.

Comment: Could it be you have hit this: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10389 ?

Comment: @SiKing Please see the EDIT.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, you don't need selenium for that. You can just use requests for the same

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tried `requests`. It does not get re-directed either. I thought I had the best chances with selenium, since the regular browser does get redirected and accessing with selenium should be like accessing with a browser...

Comment: Post the HTML response you got from requests package

Comment: @TarunLalwani `<Response [200]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your page doesn't use a 30X. Instead it use a different approach of using a `Refresh` header. Refresh header is in the form of

```
Refresh: 5; url=http://www.example.org/fresh-as-a-summer-breeze
```

Where 5 means that load url after 5 seconds. You can see how I extract the url which it redirects to using IPython + Requests

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: res = requests.get("http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS16/paper/viewFile/13951/13240")

In [3]: res
Out[3]: <Response [200]>

In [4]: res.text
Out[4]: ''

In [5]: res.headers
Out[5]: {'Date': 'Fri, 29 Sep 2017 10:52:14 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Refresh': '0; url=https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS16/paper/viewFile/13951/13240', 'Set-Cookie': 'OCSSID=c5eifnobt0942860sraccb2cs0; path=/ocs/', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}

In [6]: res.headers['Refresh']
Out[6]: '0; url=https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS16/paper/viewFile/13951/13240'

In [7]: res.headers['Refresh'].split("url=")[-1]
Out[7]: 'https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS16/paper/viewFile/13951/13240'
```

Comment: This is even better than selenium, since I do not have to wait for the re-direction to actually happen! However, I would like to make my solution general (i.e. for both *30X* and for *refresh header*). Is the following for 30X: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32528675/2725810 ? Also, are there other possibilities besides *30X* and *refresh header* to consider? Lastly, is my understanding correct that the mechanism used by the page is encoded in the HTTP response code (so that 200 stands for *refresh header* and 302 stands for *30X*)?