# Python Requets not return the last redirect url

Tags: python-3.x, http, redirect, python-requests

I have a url like `https://guangdiu.com/go.php?id=5347317`. When you open this in the browser, it will redirect 2 times. I am trying to get the last direct url.

I am trying to follow this url to get the last direct url: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url/20475639`

I tried them all, none of them worked. I am always getting the same url.

What's wrong?

Comment: Redirection is done via js. I'm afraid you'll have to use `selenium`.

Comment: @t.m.adam How do you find out it's done via js? Maybe I can find the specific js file, and figure it out.

Comment: If you print the response `.text` you'll see a script tag that redirects to a new url via `window.location`. If you follow the second url, it pulls some js from a third url via `location.replace`. If you follow the third url there is some script that sets cookies and redirects to the final url.

Comment: Below is the third url with the js that does the final redirection, in case you want to study it: https://union-click.jd.com/jdc?e=&p=AyIHZRprFQYXAlMbWCVGTV8LRGtMR1dGFxBFC1pXUwkEAEAdQFkJBVsRBxcBVRhETEdOWmVpXhFDcF4UaDhSZGR7IW4dQEAUWStNVxlsEQZVEkcUBg4GUQpYFwkTBF4eXyUCEw9SHV8QBhQGZRtaFAMTAl0ZUx0yEABUEloVChU3VRprXmwTN1QrWxEBFgNXGF8SBhYDVitcJVJHWw1ENRYDEgBlK2slMiIHZRg%3D&t=W1dCFFlQCxxKQgFHRE5XDVULR0UVBhcCUxtYCltXWwg%3D I assume that the query string is dynamic, but the script seems to be static.