# How to get final url after following http redirections in python?

Tags: python-3.x

For example:

```
http://dir.iran.ir/home?p_p_id=webdirectorydisplay_WAR_webdirectoryportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=exclusive&p_p_mode=view&_webdirectorydisplay_WAR_webdirectoryportlet_itemEntryId=14439&_webdirectorydisplay_WAR_webdirectoryportlet_cmd=redirectToLink
```

The final redirected link is :

```
http://www.dps.ir/
```

Answer (score -1):

See this answer: [Python Requests library redirect new url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20475712/10781184)

The main idea is following: After you made a urllib request with `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` it will return a HTTPResponse element. On this element you can call `.geturl()` to get the final redirected url as string:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> url = "https://python.org"
>>> http_response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
>>> url_redirected = http_response.geturl()
>>> print(url_redirected)
https://www.python.org/
```