# How can I make a URL request with Python and return the URL I am redirected to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to go to a URL, which will return a code string in the redirected url.

Example: https://exampleurl.com

2-3 seconds afterwards I get redirected to https://newurl.com/stuffhere?code=97412098512yidfh480b14r

Is there a way to return the the new URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Requests library redirect new url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [official docs](https://2.python-requests.org//en/v2.8.1/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history):

> The `Response.history` list contains the Response objects that were
>   created in order to complete the request. The list is sorted from the
>   oldest to the most recent response.

Here's an example that prints the URLs that led to the final URL:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/redirect/3')
for resp in response.history:
    print(resp.url)
```

To get the final URL only, you can simply do:

```
print(response.url)
```