# Handling redirections in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, redirect, python-requests

I have a URL that looks like `http://www.example.com/link?url=http://www.google.com`. And the URL redirects to `http://www.google.com` when opened in the browser. But when I check the status code of the URL, it shows 200 instead of 3xx. Even if I check with `print(url.history)` it shows `[]`. Please explain!

Edit: I checked the response of the request it was like :

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com';
window.location=url;
</script>
<!-- Form pop up box -->
    <div id="popUpPageConatiner" style="display:none;" ></div>
<!-- close form pop up box -->
```

Comment: This seems to be a DUPE question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Requests library redirect new url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url)

Comment: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

`requests.get` by default running with `{'allow_redirects': True}`, which means you will have `response.status_code` output `200`, not `302` or `301`.