# Is there a way to get a file's URL that downloads automatically after a few seconds on a landing page with Python?

Tags: python, html, pdf, redirect, web-scraping

After reading a lot of posts about web scraping and how to follow URL redirections with Python, I am finally compelled to ask for your help!

Here is an example of a website I am trying to scrape: http://xmaths.free.fr/1ES/cours/index.php .

My objective is to automatically download exercises and their correction in PDF. I have succeeded in saving exercises, but I am facing a problem while attempting to download the corrections PDF files.

For example, to reach a correction file, the website provides this link http://xmaths.free.fr/1ES/cours/corrige.php?nomexo=1ESpctgex01 . When you click on it, this opens a page telling you that you are going to access the correction. Then, after a few seconds, the file automatically opens with the url http://xmaths.free.fr/corrections/rMu623S1NA.pdf.

I first thought about a redirection. I have used the requests.history attribute ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20475712)) but the code returns that there is no redirection followed.

Here is the code I have written to try downloading the correction files:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

correction_urls = ['http://xmaths.free.fr/1ES/cours/indications.php?nomexo=1ESderiex01', 'http://xmaths.free.fr/1ES/cours/indications.php?nomexo=1ESderiex02', 'http://xmaths.free.fr/1ES/cours/indications.php?nomexo=1ESderian02']

# Accessing each webpage stored in correction_urls list
for i, correction_url in enumerate(correction_urls):
    r = requests.get(correction_url)
    html_doc = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
    
    # Iterate over each link on the page
    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        href = link.get("href")
        
        # Identify links to corrections
        if str(href)[0:12] == "corrige.php?":
            
            # Build the full url and access it
            correction_pdf = "http://xmaths.free.fr/1ES/cours/" + href
            r = requests.get(correction_pdf)
            
            # Rename and save the pdf file
            with open("math_correction{}.pdf".format(i+1), "wb") as f:
                f.write(r.content)
```

In this way, I do not manage to reach the final link of the PDF, but only the link of the page before the file opens.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the correct path from `<meta>` tag inside head:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1 ; url=../../corrections/rMu623S1NA.pdf">
```

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://xmaths.free.fr/1ES/cours/corrige.php?nomexo=1ESpctgex01'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
r = requests.get('http://xmaths.free.fr/1ES/cours/' + soup.meta['content'].split(';')[-1].split('=')[-1])

with open('document.pdf', 'wb') as f_out:
    f_out.write(r.content)
```