# How to get last url after redirection with JavaScript using Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, redirect

I want to get the last URL that redirected from a homepage website with JavaScript using Python:

`window.location = sameaddr`

I tried to do that with the `requests` module, but I didn't manage to get it working.

I think that the last remedy open website in background and get last URL from that.

I tried the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url) post:

```
r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
print(r.url)
```

Please help me some guidance for a solution.

- Example 1: this [site](http://apply.brooklynda.org) that redirected and I want get last URL (I want output be [this url](http://apply.brooklynda.org/videsktop/virecruitselfapply/ReDefault.aspx?Tag=5ac99fe0-6179-4760-ad89-ad269b8624c5))
- Example 2: [this site](https://ivisions.bps101.net)
- Example 3: [this site](https://phone.usacommunications.tv)