# Get site url after rediretct requests

Tags: python, web, url, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was wondering if I can get the current url after a redirect from the starting page, done with requests.

For example:

I send the reqeusts to "google.com" that instantanely sends me to "google.com/page-123456", the page number changes everytime. Can I get the "google.com/page-123456" in my script?

With selenium it can be made like this:

```
import selenium
import time

driver = (...)
driver.get('google.com')
time.sleep(2)
url = driver.current_url
```

Can be this made in reqeusts / BeautifoulSoup? How?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Requests library redirect new url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url) And if you do `r = requests.get('https://google.com')`, then `r.url` is `https://www.google.com/` so that gives you the current URL you were redirected to, if you don't want the full history.

Answer (score 1):

Try property `url` of `Request` object that you can access by `response.request`:

```py
    import requests
    response=requests.get("https://google.com")
    url=response.request.url
```