# Extracting request_token / Auth_token from a redirect url

Tags: python, authentication, url

So I am writing a script to get financial data and I am using a broker's API. The flow goes like this. the user has to login and then it is redirected to the redirect_url where it also contains the request_token in the redirect_url. I want to extract this token from the redirect_url but the URL from requests.get is not the same as the redirect URL.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

```
import requests
r = requests.get(kite.login_url())
print(r.url)
```

This is the current code that I am using. kite is the broker's API object.
Eventually I want to create a dashboard using plotly dash so if there is any solution using that also would be great.

I am using the Zerodha Kite Connect API and I have set the redirect URL to https://127.0.0.1

When I try to get r.url I get the following response:

```
https://kite.zerodha.com/connect/login?api_key={myapikey}&sess_id={somesessionid}
```

and not

```
https://127.0.0.1/?request_token={request_toke}&action=login&status=success
```

which I get when I click on the above link

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20475712/9267296) and see if that gets you what you need. Otherwise, please add more information such as the URL for the broker, the URL you are getting and a sanitized URL you want to get.

Comment: I tried what this answer recommended but I am still not able to get the final redirected URL. I'll add more info.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how to use the `kite.login_url()`.

*Disclaimer:* I know nothing about Kite itself, but from reading I can see the login flow looks quite like any other OAuth login flow.

I'm going to assume you've set up your Kite account as per [this documentation](https://kite.trade/docs/connect/v3/). This means setting up the API key, API secret and the redirect URL.

You need to have your app redirect the user to the URL that `kite.login_url()` contains.

The user is then prompted to login and accept. *This is the step that you're missing.* After the user does this, it states [here](https://kite.trade/docs/connect/v3/apps/) that the URL should change to what you need.

Comment: I have promted the user to go to kite.login_url() which then does redirect to my redirect URL. So how do get this redirect URL after the user has entered the details in the login_url is what I don't know.

Comment: I expect you need to run a server (using Flask fe) to get the values you need...

Answer (score 0):

Please set `http://localhost:4004/` as your redirect URL in the Zerodha app settings.

From next login you will be redirected to a page with URL like:
`http://localhost:4004/request_token=XXXXXX`

Get the token from the URL and you are good to go.