# What is my code missing to get a JSON response from my URL link

Tags: python, json, api

I built a python client REST API wrapper for an Okta authenticated pricing API. My code runs but I am not getting any response back. I need to be able to get a JSON response. I believe a print statement would work but I hit a wall do not know what argument to pass the print statement in order to receive a response from
"conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("sso.lukka.tech")"

```
import http.client
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import base64

def loadJson(response):
    body = response.read()
    if body == "" or body is None:
        print(("Empty response found with status " + str(response.status)))
        return {}
    else:
        return json.loads(body)

class DataPricingClient:

    def __init__(self, host, clientId, clientSecret):
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("sso.lukka.tech")
        path = "/oauth2/aus1imo2fqcx5Ik4Q0h8/v1/token"
        encodedData = base64.b64encode(bytes(f"{clientId}:{clientSecret}", "ISO-8859-1")).decode("ascii")
        authHeader = "Basic " + encodedData
        headers = {
            "Authorization": authHeader,
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
        params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "scope": "pricing"
        })

        conn.request("POST", path, params, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()

        if response.status != 200:
            raise ApiErrorException(response.status, "Failed to get access token")

        self.host = host
        self.accessToken = loadJson(response)["access_token"]

    def default_headers(self):
        return {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.accessToken
        }
    
    def _send_request(self,path):
        with http.client.HTTPSConnection(self.host) as conn:
            headers = self.default_headers()
            conn.request("GET", path, None, headers)
            response = conn.getresponse()
        return response

    def get_available_sources(self):
        path = "/v1/pricing/sources"
        return _send_request(path)

    def get_source_details(self, sourceId):
        path = f"/v1/pricing/sources/{sourceId}"
        return _send_request(path)

    def get_latest_prices(self,asOf, sourceId, pairCodes):
         path = f"/v1/pricing/sources/{sourceId} {pairCodes}"
         return _send_request(path)

    def historical_prices(self, sourceId, pairCode, begTs, endTs, fill, limit, variances):
        path = f"/v1/pricing/sources/{sourceId} {pairCode} {begTs} {endTs} {fill} {limit} {variances}"
        return _send_request(path)


class ApiErrorException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, status, msg):
        self.msg = "Error " + str(status) + ": " + msg
    def __str__(self):
        return self.msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pricing_api_creds import lukka_pricing
    c = DataPricingClient(**lukka_pricing)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is because of a redirect. The API is basically telling you you have to go to a different page. You can do that manually (by yourself) or use a library to do that. One way to do it with `http.client` is like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20475712/3352383

But I would suggest you to use [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) because it does it automatically and usually it is also easier to use. Good luck!