# How can I get the real(final) URL from shorthen or redirected url? (for scraping using python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Accepted URL : https://naver.me/xDMa0YE6 (this is shorten URL from app)

Redirected URL : https://link.naver.com/bridge?url=https%3A%2F%2Fn.news.naver.com%2Farticle%2F009%2F0004980823&dst=naversearchapp%3A%2F%2Finappbrowser%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fn.news.naver.com%252Farticle%252F009%252F0004980823%26version%3D10%26sourceReferer%3Dshare (this is redirected URL from the Accepted URL)

Final URL : https://n.news.naver.com/article/009/0004980823 (this is the final URL what I want to scrpe.

When I tried to scrape the Accepted URL, it is linked to Redirected URL, and can't scrape the html...(using bs4)

**any way to find the Final URL from the Accepted URL by using Python code??**strong text****

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Requests library redirect new url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url)

Comment: Thank you, but the answer is abt redirected url. Mine is changed 3 times.

Answer (score -2):

> way to find the Final URL from the Accepted URL by using Python code

Simple answer

```py
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get(' https://naver.me/xDMa0YE6',allow_redirects = False)
>>> r.headers['Location']
'https://link.naver.com/bridge?url=https%3A%2F%2Fn.news.naver.com%2Farticle%2F009%2F0004980823&dst=naversearchapp%3A%2F%2Finappbrowser%3Furl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fn.news.naver.com%252Farticle%252F009%252F00
04980823%26version%3D10%26sourceReferer%3Dshare'
>>> redirected = r.headers['Location']
>>> redirected.find('&')
93
>>> redirected.find('?url=')
29
>>> redirected[29+5:93]
'https%3A%2F%2Fn.news.naver.com%2Farticle%2F009%2F0004980823'
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> unquote(redirected[29:93])
'?url=https://n.news.naver.com/article/009/0004980823'
>>> unquote(redirected[29+5:93])
'https://n.news.naver.com/article/009/0004980823'
```

Why:

When you request the shortened link, you are likely to be get a respond that tell your browser to redirect, so we `allow_redirects = False` and get the redirected link in the response (by inspecting the response).

Closely inspect the link you will find a `url=` parameter, which contains the final link you need but is URL encoded. Just decode it and done.