# Python does not note every new chrome access log when retrieving target urls from redirect urls

Tags: python, google-chrome, http, url, redirect

I'm applying the code of [Shahin Shirazi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70869691/10035626) to retrieve the target url of a redirect link using Python. I'm applying this code to multiple redirect links. However, when I run this code, in some cases Python writes the target url of the previous redirect link again. Obviously, Chrome has not updated the history file on time. I already added some sleep time.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import webbrowser
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import time
import os

# ---------------------FILEREADING------------------------------------------

colnames = ['Column1']
Filename_Link = "reflinks.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(Filename_Link, names=colnames)
links = data.Column1.tolist()

# ---------------------Create a new .csv file that we are going to fill with the target urls------------------------------------------

output_data = "output_data.csv"
fd = open(output_data, "a",encoding='utf-8-sig')
topline = "url, target_url,"
fd.write(topline)
fd.write("\n")         

# ---------------------Define the history folder of the browser ------------------------------------------

#source file is where the history of your webbroser is saved, I was using chrome, but it should be the same process if you are using different browser
source_file = 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History'
# could not directly connect to history file as it was locked and had to make a copy of it in different location
destination_file = 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\History'
    

# ---------------------Run the code to get target urls for all redirect links ------------------------------------------

for link in links:
    webbrowser.open(link)
    time.sleep(30) # there is some delay to update the history file, so 30 sec wait give it enough time to make sure your last url get logged
    os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")    
    shutil.copy(source_file,destination_file) # copying the file.
    time.sleep(10) # I added some delay to copy the files
    con = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\History') # connecting to browser history
    cursor = con.execute("SELECT * FROM urls")
    names = [description[0] for description in cursor.description]
    urls = cursor.fetchall()
    con.close()
    df_history = pd.DataFrame(urls,columns=names)
    last_url = df_history.loc[len(df_history)-1,'url']
    print(last_url)
    
    fd.write(link.replace(",","").replace("\n"," "))
    fd.write(",")
    
    fd.write(last_url.replace(",","").replace("\n"," "))
    fd.write(",")
   
       
    fd.write("\n")
    
fd.close()
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: but WHY? unless website is using javascript for redirect(then you have Selenium) `requests`  should handle it well.

Comment: Can you tell what you would propose exactly? Which code are you referring to?

Comment: "retrieve the target url of a redirect link using Python"?? the linked answer has so many good solutions and you choose one with 0 score.

Comment: The reason is the other answers did not work for my case. Correct me if I'm wrong. Here is the redirect link: https://www.mydealz.de/visit/threadmain/2127697

Comment: all you need is a http header with proper UA string `headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get('https://www.mydealz.de/visit/threadmain/2127697', headers = headers)
print(r.url)`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, life can be so easy...