# How to check if the url redirect to another url using Python

Tags: python, urllib2, redirect

I want to check whether the target url will be redirected after visiting. I thought I could do something like this:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url=url, headers=headers)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=3)
code = resp.code
if code == '200': # valid
else: # not valid
```

But it does not work since even if the url redirects, I still get 200. Can anyone help me with this plz?

Comment: `resp.geturl()` will give you the final url. You can compare your original url with the final url and detect a redirect.

Comment: req = urllib2.Request(starturl, datagen, headers)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
finalurl = res.geturl()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the URL of a redirect with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902523/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-redirect-with-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to elaborate on my comment:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url=url, headers=headers)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=3)
redirected = resp.geturl() != url # redirected will be a boolean True/False
```

Answer (score 0):

What about http `HEAD` request?. There is code snippet using `requests` library

```
import requests
r = requests.head(url)
redirected = r.headers['location'] != url  # True / False
redirect_url = r.url  # OR r.headers['location']
```