# Reverse AMP url with python (get regular URL from amp)

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, amp-html

How would I go about reversing the process of Google's AMP api?

I am looking to take an AMP (accelerated mobile page) URL and come up with the regular (original) URL. I was wondering if anyone has the answer as to how to do this in Python (or any other language for that matter)?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

An example:

https://amp.cnn.com/cnn/2018/03/08/politics/jeff-flake-anti-tariff-bill/

Expected output:
https://cnn.com/2018/03/08/politics/jeff-flake-anti-tariff-bill/

A second example:

https://www.google.ca/amp/s/mobile.nytimes.com/2018/03/08/us/politics/trump-tariff-announcement.amp.html

Expected output:
https://www.nytimes.com/2018/03/08/us/politics/trump-tariff-announcement.html

A third (and final) example:

https://www.google.ca/amp/s/www.theverge.com/platform/amp/2018/3/8/17097904/android-ios-smartphone-brand-loyalty

Expected output:
https://www.theverge.com/2018/3/8/17097904/android-ios-smartphone-brand-loyalty

The unfortunate thing is that the implementation of AMP appears to vary considerably. I guess one approach could be to just chop out any "amp" and surrounding dots (.) or slashes (/), however, I could imagine a scenario where that would not be the wisest approach (mainly if the page URL *actually was* supposed to have amp in its ending etc (and it appeared in regular browsing).

Comment: Can you pls clarify this a little more - not sure what you mean. Maybe add a concrete example like a url/link as an input and what you would expect as an output

Comment: @daKmoR added 3 examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this in the future, I thought I would share my solution. Using the information from @daKmoR, I was able to eventually come up with the following:

```
import metadata_parser
page = metadata_parser.MetadataParser(url="https://amp.cnn.com/cnn/2018/03/08/politics/jeff-flake-anti-tariff-bill/ ")
#page = metadata_parser.MetadataParser(url="https://www.google.ca/amp/s/www.theverge.com/platform/amp/2018/3/8/17097904/android-ios-smartphone-brand-loyalty/")
#print(page.metadata)
#TODO: Doesnt work for verge
print("New")
real_URL = page.get_metadata_link('url')
if real_URL:
    print(real_URL)
else:
    print("Boo")
```

If you run into errors like "TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION", then you are probably compiling with an outdated Python version. "metadata_parser" referenced above is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/jvanasco/metadata_parser).

EDIT:
Here is the updated code per @sebastian-benz 's response.

```
import metadata_parser
#page = metadata_parser.MetadataParser(url="https://amp.cnn.com/cnn/2018/03/08/politics/jeff-flake-anti-tariff-bill/ ")
page = metadata_parser.MetadataParser(url="https://www.google.ca/amp/s/mobile.nytimes.com/2018/03/08/us/politics/trump-tariff-announcement.amp.html")
#print(page.metadata)
#TODO: Doesnt work for verge
print("New")
#real_URL = page.get_metadata_link('url')
real_URL = page.get_url_canonical()
if real_URL:
    print(real_URL)
else:
    print("Boo")
```

Answer (score 2):

AMP pages are required to reference their canonical version via:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/full/document.html">
```

The correct way to discover the non-AMP version of a page, is to fetch the AMP document and extract the href value of it's canonical link tag.

You can read more about this in the [official documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/discovery).

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3, another option could be opening the url and getting the final url from the response.
Following @jadelord's answer on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902523/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-redirect-with-python):

```
import urllib
def resolve(url):
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url).geturl()
```